# not able to see image in Android Emulator

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

I am not able to see an image when running with the Android emulator.

I have made a test solution that does nothing else than just showing an image on MainPage.xaml.
I have imported the image into the same folder as the xaml file using the solution explorer clicking: add existing item.

the xaml is nothing special, just showing the image:

```
<StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Image Source="myPicture.png"/>
</StackLayout>
```

There is no error message, just the picture doesn't appear.
Anything I have have forgotten to add or configure in order to show the picture on the emulator?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please take the time to read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Comment: Did you understand how image works in xamarin.forms with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

> I have imported the image into the same folder as the xaml file using
>   the solution explorer clicking: add existing item.

You are adding the image as [embedded-images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images) in xamarin.forms project. So, you could access the image by using:

```
var embeddedImage = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromResource("myPicture.jpg", typeof(EmbeddedImages).GetTypeInfo().Assembly) };
```

If you want to show the image by using `<Image Source="myPicture.png"/>`, you should  add the image files to **each application project** which referenced from Xamarin.Forms shared code:

- iOS

> The preferred way to manage and support images since iOS 9 is to use
>   **Asset Catalog Image Sets**, which should contain all of the versions of
>   an image that are necessary to support various devices and scale
>   factors for an application. For more information, see Adding Images to
>   an Asset Catalog Image Set.

- Android

> Place images in the **Resources/drawable** directory with Build Action:
>   AndroidResource. High- and low-DPI versions of an image can also be
>   supplied (in appropriately named Resources subdirectories such as
>   drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-xhdpi).

- Universal Windows Platform (UWP)

> Place images in the application's root directory with Build Action:
>   Content.

Then you can show the image by:

```
<Image Source="myPicture.jpg" />
```

Or

```
var image = new Image { Source = "myPicture.jpg" };
```

Document is here: [local-images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)